# How to customize the arrows in React-slick if I am also using styled components

Tags: react-slick

I can't seem to change the colors and size of the left and right arrows on the carousel.Since I am using styled components for style,and the  component is wrapped inside a styled version of it.Also I can not use the slick-after:before trick even though I tried.

These are my settings and what I have tried is to specify new components for the left and right arrow,but then I have to provide the functionality and I can't seem to find how that works in the docs either.

const settings = {
infinite: true,
speed: 500,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
adaptiveHeight: true,
};